# Right way to get random bytes from entropy audio source

Tags: c#, random, entropy

i create application to generate random passwords, i've used microsoft algorithm implemented in [Membership](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.Web/Security/Membership.cs) class as example. I made decision to use user voice as entropy source, i get sha1 of audio file and use bytes to get values of password:

```
 using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open))
 using (BufferedStream bs = new BufferedStream(fs))
 {
     using (SHA1Managed sha1 = new SHA1Managed())
     {
         byte[] hash = sha1.ComputeHash(bs);

         var pass = BitConverter.ToString(hash).Replace("-", string.Empty);

     }
 }
```

Please tell me passwords has been generated by this way is it Random ? Or i have to process audio file in different way ?

Comment: What do you hope to achieve by using the user's voice rather than e.g. `RNGCryptoServiceProvider`, as in the Microsoft implementation you linked to?

Comment: There's a difference between using the user's voice (print) as the actual *password*, and using it as an *entropy source*. The latter doesn't make much sense, especially since the voice data will be anything *but* random, and (as mentioned) `RNGCryptoServiceProvider` will already use all the entropy available to the OS. You could mix in the voice data with the entropy, but that requires a lot of care and attention to avoid actually reducing the entropy and is almost certainly not worth the effort.

Comment: @Rotem I just practice, actually I want add a my own entropy source instead of in RNGCryptoServiceProvider uses, and I create Telegram Bot, and I think it is good idea to get entropy

Comment: @JeroenMostert ok, thanks, I just want use for practice, I have read many articles about entropy, and all of them contain audio from microphone as source, but I don't know how to process it to get correct random.

Comment: That's a big topic that requires the attention of a cryptography expert. Running the data through SHA-1 as a randomness extractor isn't a bad approach, but then you still need a way to combine that with the entropy of the system -- if everything is sufficiently random, an XOR from the output of `RNGCryptoServiceProvider` would do, but is that really enough? I would not, personally, feel confident enough to do such a thing as opposed to just relying on the system entropy. See [here](http://blog.cr.yp.to/20140205-entropy.html) for some good material on why more isn't always better.

Comment: @JeroenMostert thanks for your advice and link.